# keyboard gets locked when editing source controlled files using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard, source-control-bindings

I am facing a strange issue with editing source controlled files (especially aspx files) using visual studio 2008. when I check out and edit the file, I can edit fine for few seconds and after that keyboard gets locked and I can't type anything (it doesn't affect the files not added to source control). as soon it is locked, if I try to type, the focus shifts to solution explorer and other windows and sometimes it freezes and doesn't respond at all. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling visual studio, reinstalling the source control plug-in. none of it worked. not sure if it is my machine or my profile. Please help if you have any clues. I can't see any other solution for this except rebuilding the machine

Update: I use Perforce plug-in for source control

Thanks,
Rama

Comment: It might help if you said what source control system you were using and especially what plugin.